# After migrating 6.1 project to mobilefirst platform 6.3, application getting stuck on splash screen

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I have migrated my 6.1 project to 6.3 its getting stuck on splash screen. After sometime it showing white screen.
its not calling initOptions function also or else deviceready also. Is there any solution?

Comment: If you want to get help you will need to provide more information, like logs, which environment/device this is tested on, your full build number of 6.3 and a test project where this is reproducible so it could be tested (provide the 6.1 version so we could do the migration ourselves).

Comment: You have not mentioned which environment . Post migration, have you tried removing the environment and adding it again and then try deploying.

Answer (score 0):

Without the requested sample application to debug we cannot help further.

The only alternative is to replicate your app in a new project and application in MobileFirst Studio 6.3 by copying over the contents of the HTML, JS and CSS (and any custom native code you may have implemented).